# Two section for listview android

Tags: android, listview, adapter

I have a sectioned `listview` with dynamic data. I wanted to section as 1st part and 2nd part.

I have 2 adapter class , 1 Listview

I wanted 2 adapter class to merge with Section (Header)

```
summaryOrderAdapter = new SummaryOrderAdapter(getActivity(), summaryOrderListData);
summaryNinjaAdapter = new SummaryNinjaAdapter(getActivity(), summaryNinjaListData);

summaryListView.addView(headerView);
summaryListView.setAdapter(summaryOrderAdapter);

summaryListView.addView(headerView_);
summaryListView.setAdapter(summaryNinjaAdapter);
```

> Getting Error : java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: addView(View) is not supported in AdapterView

Answer (score 0):

The problem is ListView is a AdapterView, which only takes subviews from its adapter. It's adapter is responsible for supplying item views to ListView.

I'm not sure I understand your question. If you are trying to use sectioned list view, then use two ListViews and two Adapters, put the two ListView inside a vertical LinearLayout. If you are trying to combine a ListView with other views, also use a ViewGroup(i.e. LinearLayout) as a container.

Comment: The main problem is I don't want the items in Listview to be scrollable . I wanted the entire screen to scroll not the litview item . So used 1 Listview

Comment: then you can use one listview with one adapter, and let the adapter do the data merging work (access data from two datasets and display them at appropriate places in the listview).

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by using the MergerAdapter library Here's [a link](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-merge)